# How to get list of files managed by Spring-Cloud-Config-Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have 3 Spring-Boot applications running:

1. Eureka:8761
2. Spring-Cloud-Config:8080
3. myMicroService:8181

For Spring-Cloud-Config, I am using a local git URI to populate data. The local repo is on branch `master` and has a file structure like this:

```
./myMicroService
  |-- application.properties
  |-- foo.txt
  |-- bar.txt
```

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_serving_plain_text), I can access the text files like this:

http://localhost:8080/myMicroService/default/master/foo.txt
http://localhost:8080/myMicroService/default/master/bar.txt

Which works, but **how do I get the full list of available *.txt files served up by Spring-Cloud-Config server?**

I tried this:

http://localhost:8080/myMicroService/default/master

Which only returns `application.properties` and its values.

Comment: There is not a way to do this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given there is no OOTB solution for this, I added a new request mapping to my config-server:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
@EnableEurekaClient
@RestController
public class ConfigServer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ConfigServer.class, args);
  }

  @Value("${spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri}")
  private String uri;

  @Autowired private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

  @GetMapping("/{name}/{profile}/{label}/listFiles")
  public Collection<String> retrieve(
      @PathVariable String name,
      @PathVariable String profile,
      @PathVariable String label,
      HttpServletRequest request)
      throws IOException {
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(uri);
    String uriPath = resource.getFile().getPath();
    Path namePath = Paths.get(uriPath, name);
    String baseUrl =
        String.format(
            "http://%s:%d/%s/%s/%s",
            request.getServerName(), request.getServerPort(), name, profile, label);
    try (Stream<Path> files = Files.walk(namePath)) {
      return files
          .map(Path::toFile)
          .filter(File::isFile)
          .map(File::getName)
          .map(filename -> baseUrl + "/" + filename)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
  }
}
```

getting list of files for myMicroService:

```
curl http://localhost:8888/myMicroService/default/master/listFiles
```

result:

```
[
   "http://localhost:8888/myMicroService/default/master/application.properties",
   "http://localhost:8888/myMicroService/default/master/foo.txt",
   "http://localhost:8888/myMicroService/default/master/bar.txt"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous solution from  assumes that your **spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri** is of **https** type.  The solution below will reference the local filesystem that contains the files that have been pulled from the repo and will work with any repo type.  The endpoints also accept a search path and take the format of:

- `/{name}/{profile}/{label}/{path}/listFiles`
- `/{name}/{profile}/{path}/listFiles?useDefaultLabel`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigServer
@RestController
public class CloudConfigApplication {

    private UrlPathHelper helper = new UrlPathHelper();

    private SearchPathLocator service;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudConfigApplication.class, args);
    }

    public CloudConfigApplication(SearchPathLocator service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/{name}/{profile}/{label}/**/listFiles")
    public List<String> retrieve(@PathVariable String name, @PathVariable String profile,
                                 @PathVariable String label, ServletWebRequest request,
                                 @RequestParam(defaultValue = "true") boolean resolvePlaceholders)
            throws IOException {
        String path = getDirPath(request, name, profile, label);
        return listAll(request, name, profile, label, path);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}/{profile}/**/listFiles", params = "useDefaultLabel")
    public List<String> retrieve(@PathVariable String name, @PathVariable String profile,
                                 ServletWebRequest request,
                                 @RequestParam(defaultValue = "true") boolean resolvePlaceholders)
            throws IOException {
        String path = getDirPath(request, name, profile, null);
        return listAll(request, name, profile, null, path);
    }

    private String getDirPath(ServletWebRequest request, String name, String profile, String label) {
        String stem;
        if (label != null) {
            stem = String.format("/%s/%s/%s/", name, profile, label);
        } else {
            stem = String.format("/%s/%s/", name, profile);
        }
        String path = this.helper.getPathWithinApplication(request.getRequest());
        path = path.substring(path.indexOf(stem) + stem.length()).replace("listFiles", "");
        return path;
    }

    public synchronized List<String> listAll(ServletWebRequest request, String application, String profile, String label, String path) {
        if (StringUtils.hasText(path)) {
            String[] locations = this.service.getLocations(application, profile, label).getLocations();
            List<String> fileURIs = new ArrayList<>();

            try {
                int i = locations.length;

                while (i-- > 0) {
                    String location = String.format("%s%s", locations[i], path).replace("file:", "");
                    Path filePath = new File(location).toPath();
                    if(Files.exists(filePath)) {
                        fileURIs.addAll(Files.list(filePath).filter(file -> !Files.isDirectory(file)).map(file -> {
                            String URL =
                                    String.format(
                                            "%s://%s:%d%s/%s/%s/%s%s?useDefaultLabel",
                                            request.getRequest().getScheme(), request.getRequest().getServerName(),
                                            request.getRequest().getServerPort(), request.getRequest().getContextPath(),
                                            application, profile, path,
                                            file.getFileName().toString());
                            if(label != null) {
                                URL = String.format(
                                        "%s://%s:%d%s/%s/%s/%s/%s%s",
                                        request.getRequest().getScheme(), request.getRequest().getServerName(),
                                        request.getRequest().getServerPort(), request.getRequest().getContextPath(),
                                        application, profile, label, path,
                                        file.getFileName().toString());
                            }
                            return URL;
                        }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException var11) {
                throw new NoSuchResourceException("Error : " + path + ". (" + var11.getMessage() + ")");
            }
            return fileURIs;
        }
        throw new NoSuchResourceException("Not found: " + path);
    }
}
```

**Getting the list:**

```
curl http://localhost:8080/context/appName/profile/label/some/path/listFiles
```

**Example Results:**

```
[
   "http://localhost:8080/context/appName/profile/label/some/path/robots.txt"
]
```